# ASP.NET MVC - Forbidden 403.14 on previously working site

Tags: asp.net, git, iis-express

I uninstalled the Visual Studio Tools for Git so I could reinstall a later version (it was doing strange things like leaving merge markers in files).

Since then, in a mixed ASP.NET WebForms and MVC 4 project, I can no longer visit MVC routed URLS. I get;

> HTTP Error 403.14
>
> Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I've also made some code changes, but I rolled back all these changes and the problem is still there. I then deployed to another environment and all is well.

I will report back with what I find. Pretty bad experience so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I push all changes up and then cloned to a new folder. It works in the new folder!

I make a branch in the new folder and delete everything, copy-in the broken folder contents and see what Git thinks has changed, see what the difference is that breaks the site.

All sorts of differences found, all of them whitespace, CRLF issues with Git. I love Git.

I checkout a long previous version. That doesn't work.

I open a another MVC4 project, that works! So MVC and IISX 8 are able to serve pages, just not from this project (even from an old commit that was working).

This is serious problem. It worked for a moment and then not.

**Update**

So I clone again into another new folder. It works. Let's see how long this lasts.

**Update**

I check out my changes branch and it still works. The last time I broke it, it was after copying the broken contents in from the other repo folder, Git told me that the modifications were all whitespace.

So whitespace or Linux LF characters caused a 403 and ruined my Friday.